# Working with Methods. Declaring variables globally

Tags: java

I have just started learning and I am really struggling to make my methods work. I have tried declaring the variables num1 and num2 globally but nothing will work. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MinMax 
{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //a re-useable method to get the numbers
    public static void getNumbers()
    {
        int num1, num2;
        System.out.println("Please enter number 1");
        num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter number 2");
        num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    //getNumbers

    public static void printAnswer(int pNum1, int pNum2)
    {
        if (pNum1 > pNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("Number 1 is the max number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Number 2 is the max number");
        }
    }//printAnswer

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {  
        getNumbers();
        printAnswer(num1, num2);
        getNumbers();
        printAnswer(num1, num2);

    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: how do you make global variables ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you didn't declare  `num1, num2` globally. You have declared it inside `getNumbers()` function which is local to this function. You need to declare it in the context of class as you have declared your `KeyBoard` instance of `Scanner` and right below(or up) of it. For example:

```
public class MinMax
{   
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int num1, num2;

//a re-useable method to get the numbers
public static void getNumbers()
{

    System.out.println("Please enter number 1");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter number 2");
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
}

//........... your other code
}
```

The reason that you have to declare the `num1` and `num2` variables with *static* modifier is that you can't access *non-static class variables* from *static* context(such as the `getNumbers()` method here).

Comment: @user2810581, There are many answer here. The common use of this site is to mark the answer(with Green tick mark)  as accepted which satisfies your question. The choice of the answer is completely yours. Thank you and welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: @Sage - In order to make this answer the best it can be(it's already accepted, though), could you please add the explanation behind, why using `static` solved the OP's problem?!

Comment: @R.J, yes, thank you for suggesting. I will update the answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static int num1, num2; // I think you tried without the static keyword, and that's why it didnt work
```

You need to make them static, just below the `Scanner` declaration, because just like Scanner object, you're using them in `static` methods. That's why if they are not static, you can't use them in static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Declare num1 and num2 as class attributes; you have declared them as local variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class MinMax
{   static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int num1, num2;

//a re-useable method to get the numbers
public static void getNumbers()
{    
    System.out.println("Please enter number 1");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter number 2");
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
}//getNumbers

public static void printAnswer(int pNum1, int pNum2)
{
    if (pNum1 > pNum2)
    {
        System.out.println("Number 1 is the max number");
    }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Number 2 is the max number");
        }
}//printAnswer

public static void main(String [] args)
{  
    getNumbers();
    printAnswer(num1, num2);
    getNumbers();
    printAnswer(num1, num2);

}//main
}//class
```

Global variables are declared inside your class and not inside methods. Also, note that you have to make the variables static because you're using them in static methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables num1 and num2 as static in your class, check this [working sample](http://ideone.com/wI1622)

```
class Ideone
{
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   //declare it as class variables
    static int num1;
    static int num2;

    //a re-useable method to get the numbers
    public static void getNumbers()
    {
        // int num1, num2; this declare two locals variables
        System.out.println("Please enter number 1");
        num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter number 2");
        num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    //getNumbers

    public static void printAnswer(int pNum1, int pNum2)
    {
        if (pNum1 > pNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("Number 1 is the max number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Number 2 is the max number");
        }
    }//printAnswer

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {  
        getNumbers();
        printAnswer(num1, num2);
        getNumbers();
        printAnswer(num1, num2);

    }//main
}
```